# Oraclm32.dll missing error when I try to run my application

Tags: oracle

I am currently working in Windows 7 32 bit system and my application has to run in a Windows 8 64-bit system which is the server. If sever side Oracle 64 is installed whether can I able to run my application there?

If I try to run I am getting error as oraclm32.dll is missing.

Can anyone help me is resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Oracle server prloblem, but client.

You can provide some more details about the architecture of your application.
Your application is a 32bit exe, so loads the oracle client 32bit.

32bit oracle client can connect to 64bit oracle server, no problem.

Installation of oracle server, includes oracle client with same architecture (in your case 64bit), but manually Oracle client can be installed twice, 32bit and 64bit on the same machine.

Take a look on Oracle instant client, can be a good choice for installing Oralce client on a server environment.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html

Hope it helps.